# while loop in java giving wrong outputs and not working correctly

Tags: java, while-loop

Im trying to get specfic outputs using these inputs:1 2 2 1 3 -1. The ouputs are suppose to be                  Count of positive integers is: 5
The highest value is: 3
The lowest value is: 1
The average is: 1.8
HOwever, im keep getting the wrong outputs for low and average value

```
   import java.util.Scanner;

   public class Main {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
          Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
          int num, max, low, sum;
          num= scnr.nextInt();
          max = num;
          low =0;
          sum=0;
          int count = 0;
          double avg=0;
      
          while(num>=0  )
          {
             num=scnr.nextInt();
        
             if(num<max)
              {
               low = num; 
              }
             else 
             {
                max=num;
             }
             sum+= num;
             count++;
          
          }
      
     
          avg=(double)sum/count;
          System.out.println("Count of positive integers is: "+count);
          System.out.println("The highest value is: "+max);
          System.out.println("The lowest value is: "+low);
          System.out.println("The average is: "+ avg);

      
       }
     }
```

Comment: Why ```if(num<max)``` then ```low = num; ```?

Comment: im trying to get the lowest number out of the inputs. So when num is less than max. Low becomes the lowest number out of all the inputs

Comment: But think of this scenario, say you are now having low = 5, max = 50, and the next number is 20. If following your logic, you will have low = 20.

Comment: I understand, but i don't know what to put in the if statement

Answer (score 0):

For the suggested changes, I will stick to your code structure and you can further refine it:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num, max, low, sum;
        num = scnr.nextInt();
        max = num;
        // Should not set low = 0, you should set low to the first read number also
        low = num;
        // You have already read one number above, sum should start from num
        sum = num;
        // You have already read one number above, count should start from 1
        int count = 1;
        double avg = 0;
      
        while (num >= 0)
        {
            num = scnr.nextInt();
            // You have to stop while loop if num < 0, you do not want to count negative number
            if (num < 0)
                break;
                
            // If you have number smaller than low, set it
            if (num < low)
                low = num;
            
            // If you have number bigger than max, set it
            if (num > max)
                max = num;
            
            sum += num;
            count++;
        }
      
     
        avg = (double)sum / (double)count;
        System.out.println("Count of positive integers is: " + count);
        System.out.println("The highest value is: " + max);
        System.out.println("The lowest value is: " + low);
        System.out.println("The average is: " + avg);
    }
}
```

But note that there is a flaw for the above code if your input is only `-1`. I will leave this to you to have a try on how to fix that.

Comment: thanks man for the help and explanation. Also why would the while loop be counting -1 as a input because I put it as  while (num >= 0) and I thought it wouldn't count the negative.

Comment: Because the main line to take in your number input is this: ```num = scnr.nextInt();```. If you do not do something to stop the while-loop, it will proceed with the remaining codes within the loop first before exiting.